# Is there a mySQL connection time limit?

Tags: mysql, perl

I'm using Net-SNMP on an Ubuntu 14.04 server to capture SNMP traps in snmptrapd, which I've set up (using "perl do '/path/to/traphandler.pl'" in the /etc/snmp/snmptrapd.conf) to call a Perl::DBI script to insert data into a mySQL database.  Everything has been running fine since 16th March, then about 9am yesterday (6th April - Bank Holiday - typical) the database updates stopped, though the syslog shows that the traps were still coming in.

I can't see anything obvious in /var/log, so I'm wondering whether the database connection simply expired and closed.  Does that happen?  I stopped and restarted snmptrapd and it all started working again, which makes me think that was the cause.  How would I check?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is 28800 seconds

```
connect_timeout=28800
wait_timeout=28800
interactive_timeout=28800
```

You can set the values in `/etc/my.cnf`

If you want to change it then you have to run this query:

```
SET GLOBAL interactive_timeout = 100;  //Change it if you want
SET GLOBAL wait_timeout = 100;
```

Comment: Looks like wait_timeout did the damage.  28800 secs = 8 hours and over Easter Sunday/Bank Holiday Monday the SNMP trap daemon stopped receiving traps, so the DB connection timed out.  Before that, it looks like there was never an 8-hour break in trap messages.

Answer (score 4):

If a service needs a database connection, the best is to check in the main loop or before each query if the connection is still available.

If the connection is no longer available or if it doesn't work anymore, you can close it properly and reconnect.

This way, the deamon continues to work even if the database server is temporarily unavailable. For instance, the service will continue to work even if the database server restarts.

Comment: Sound advice.  I'll add the check/reconnect code to my trap handler.  The only reason I haven't flagged yours as the "accepted" answer is that you haven't directly answered the question of whether there's a timeout.

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly an answer to your question but you can handle lost db connections without altering a timeout or checking the connection before each query.

If you access MySQL databases with DBI you can set the flag `mysql_auto_reconnect` ( see [DBD::mysql](http://search.cpan.org/~capttofu/DBD-mysql-4.025/lib/DBD/mysql.pm#DATABASE_HANDLES) )

> This attribute determines whether DBD::mysql will automatically reconnect to mysql if the connection be lost. This feature defaults to off; [..]
>   Setting mysql_auto_reconnect to on is not advised if 'lock tables' is used because if DBD::mysql reconnect to mysql all table locks will be lost.

Example:

```
  my $dbh = DBI->connect(
    $host,
    $user,
    $password,
    {    
        mysql_auto_reconnect => 1                                            
    }    
  )  or die("DB connect failed: : $DBI::errstr");
```

Comment: Neat!  That'll save me having to put in the code to detect a drop just so I can reconnect :-)